# Text and figures side by side

Tags: graphics, floats, text

[image: The output im trying to get]

Im having trouble with the first part where the text cant be side by side with the figure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image and table side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318548/image-and-table-side-by-side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section{Text and image side by side}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
  Here and there, everywhere.
  Somebody, anybody, nobody.
  Always, for ever, never.

  Here and there, everywhere.
  Somebody, anybody, nobody.
  Always, for ever, never. 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\raisebox{-1\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}}

\section{Table and image side by side}

\begin{tabular}[b]{l}
  \textbf{Abra Ka Dabra}\\
  ABC 123\\
  Holter di polter\\
  Email: A.K.Dabra@liamg.moc
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\raisebox{-1.5\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}}
```